# Permission to parent and child folders in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu. Giving permission to folder using the following command in Terminal.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/
```

This command is working for **html** folder only. But, I have many sub folders in **html** folder.

How can i give **777** permissions to all the sub folders at a time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you really want to do is set the directories to 755 and either leave the files alone or set them to 777. For this, you can use the find command. For example:

To change all the directories to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x):

```
find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the files to 777 :

```
find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It's working nice. But see the screenshot. Again it is stopping installing the plugins, like stopping the permissions.

Comment: have to give all the permissions like read/write/modify to all the folders.

Comment: Yes, @Ajeeb it is working. I have given find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;  to all the directories.  Thanks for your help